# Wi-Fi Direct Frame Exchange

Tags: wireless-networking

In a working Wi-FI Direct Scenario, I have read that after three way handshake of GO negotiation, the GO starts sending the beacon and the client sends the probe request and then the authentication request.(According to many P2P articles)

But when I captured the packets between two P2P devices, after GO selection , the GO sending probe response and then only moves to sending beacon.

I really wish to whether the Wi-Fi Direct implementation follows the exact theory of frame exchange.

As I have an issue with Group formation in WFD ICS, I am bit confused whether to trace the what happens to beacon or probe response, as the client is sending probe request but GO not responding with any kind of management frame and later moving to " Group Formation Timeout"

According to the below logcat messages

```
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: Probe Request for PBC received from ca:dd:c9:f2:0f:f8
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: Checking active PBC sessions for overlap
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: Add one for the requested UUID
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: Consider PBC session with ca:dd:c9:f2:0f:f8
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: 1 active PBC session(s) found
```

I got to know that the GO is getting the probe request from ca:dd:c9:f2:0f:f8 the client. How the GO should respond to it ? I guess through a probe response. But according to articles the GO sends beacon. I am bit confused with these probe response and beacon from GO. In my case GO is not sending any frames and I am getting Group Formation failed message later

Comment: Hi Krishna. I find your question difficult to understand; there's something that might be your question in the third paragraph, but I don't really see any specific question here. Please [edit] your question to include a *specific* question.

Comment: okay. sorry for that.... I meant by analyzing the logcat messages  09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: Probe Request for PBC received from ca:dd:c9:f2:0f:c3
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: Checking active PBC sessions for overlap
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: Add one for the requested UUID
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: Consider PBC session with ca:dd:c9:f2:0f:c3
09-10 20:21:44.904  3757  3757 D wpa_supplicant: WPS: 1 active PBC session(s) found

Comment: Is this correct?  When the P2P device becomes the Group Owner it has to sent out the beacon frames. So the other P2P device receives this beacon and send out probe request and my GO device receives it with "WPS: Probe Request for PBC received from ca:dd:c9:f2:0f:f8 " . As soon as an beaconing AP receives a probe request it will send out the response. So now I am clear about the instance when a normal AP sends out beacon and probe response. I hope this is exactly what happens with Wi-Fi Direct Group owner which is also an AP. The client expects a probe response from GO

Comment: I tried this too. When I scan from normal Wi-Fi option I can see the G0 name as DIRECT-LT-Android_6c4f ,which means it is beaconing....and disappears later from the AP list when the group formation fails and the beacons stop